# radare2: qualified vs. unqualified flags?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, debug-symbols, radare2

If I define a flag in radare2 without a prefix, like this:

```
fs symbols
f myflag=0x412
```

Then radare will show this label on the target address:

```
        ╎   ;-- myflag:
       ┌──> 0x00000412      200689         jsr 0x8906                  ;[2]
       ╎╎   0x00000415      c602           dec 0x02
       └──< 0x00000417      d0f9           bne 0x000412
```

But will *not* use this label in the target of branch statements (see, e.g., `bne 0x000412`).

On the other hand, if I define the label with a prefix, like this:

```
fs symbols
f x.myflag=0x412
```

Then the label is *also* used in branch statements:

```
        ╎   ;-- x.myflag:
       ┌──> 0x00000412      200689         jsr 0x8906                  ;[2]
       ╎╎   0x00000415      c602           dec 0x02
       └──< 0x00000417      d0f9           bne x.myflag
```

The [documenation](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/basic_commands/flags.html) on this topic doesn't seem to mention this difference in behavior. Is this expected? Is there a way to get radare2 to resolve branch destinations using unqualified flags?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I found that the following commands `f myflag.=0x412` and `f .myflag=0x412` result in the same behavior. Also interesting, the command `f. myflag=0x412` results in `0x00000417 d0f9 bne .myflag` even though the "." is part of the command not the flagname. The `f.blah=$$+12` command is used to create local function labels.